# append() does it twice! in drop part of the script jQuery + UI

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-droppable

I don't see why this `append()`  does it twice.

**This is into a call back function and corresponds to what must be done after a drag occured. (UI)**

A bunch of a treatment are done to identify the dragged div and some corresponding text we want to display (it's a kind of "choose an answer and drag&drop it on the right case).
in the drop sequence :

```
.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){ //this full code below..
```

I get the html of an already existing div (display:none) and want to add it to a div we just show. This way we inject a good content into the answer div.
But this append() does the job twice (?)  and i get  the text 2 times.

```
set_drag = function(){
    //on retire les clones inutiles
    jQuery('.cible').not('#cas1bcible, #cas2bcible, #cas3bcible, #cas4bcible').remove();

    // on garde l'img pour garder les dim du div
    jQuery('.cible > img').fadeTo(0, 0);
    jQuery('.cible').droppable({
// tout ce qui se passe si on drop
    drop: function(event, ui){
            //on récupère l'id de la forme droppée
            var forme_drag = jQuery(ui.draggable);
            var drag_id = jQuery(forme_drag).attr('id');

            //extraction du code réponse - 2 dernier caract de l'id
            var rep_num = '#rep' + drag_id.slice(-2);
            var forme_ok = jQuery(ui.draggable).attr('class');

            //Il faut afficher le texte d'accompagnement qqsoit la réponse
            //Logo et titre
            var n_texte = (drag_id).slice(-2).slice(0, -1);
            var titre_rep = '<div id="titre-rep">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/pt-logo-pnr.gif" alt="logo pnr" /><h3>Le PNR vous conseille</h3><h4>Cas ' + n_texte + '</h4></div>'
            var textID = '#txt' + n_texte;
            var le_texte = jQuery(textID).html();

            jQuery('.continuer').show();
            //on gère si ok ou pas
            if (jQuery(forme_drag).hasClass('ok')) {
                //Gestion du BON
                //affiche le coucou un peu + heut que la zone de drop
                //jQuery('#bravo').css('top', '10px').show(300);
                // affiche la réponse prévue
                jQuery('#reponses, #back-reponses').slideDown(300, function(){
                    //jQuery(rep_num).show().fadeTo('slow', 1, 'linear');
                    jQuery(rep_num).append(le_texte);
                    jQuery(rep_num).addClass('rep_ok').show().css('opacity', 1);

                });
                // insertion de la titraille
                jQuery('#reponses').append(titre_rep);

                // on rend draggable la réponse ...si on veut la bouger
                jQuery('.reponse').draggable({
                    refreshPositions: true,
                    containment: 'parent',
                    opacity: 0.65,
                    snap: false,
                    cursor: 'move',
                });

            }
            else {
                //gestion du FAUX
                // on identifie chaque réponses fausse pour faire disparaitre la forme ensuite
                jQuery(forme_drag).addClass('faux'); 

               // jQuery('#faux').css('top', '10px').show(300);
               // affiche la réponse prévue
                jQuery('#reponses, #back-reponses').slideDown(300, function(){
                    //jQuery(rep_num).show().fadeTo('slow', 1, 'linear');
                    jQuery(rep_num).append(le_texte);
                    jQuery(rep_num).addClass('rep_faux').show().css('opacity', 1);

                });

                jQuery('#reponses').append(titre_rep);
                jQuery('.reponse').draggable({
                    refreshPositions: true,
                    containment: 'parent',
                    opacity: 0.65,
                    snap: false,
                    cursor: 'move',

                });

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I can only imagine how hard it must be to write code when the entire programming language's syntax uses a foreign language....

Comment: Wayne :
ok I put all the code in http://jsfiddle.net/elz64/gVqus/
However it can't be run  (no images).

mblase75:
Thanks for your concern but  can we get back to the topic please ?

Answer (score 0):

I made it working as intended moving the append() instruction outside the if/else statement.

(???)

In my case it's ok because the txt to be appended is finally not depending on this test, and could be done right after it too, but it remains weird.

Comment: huh..seriously  this thread dated from 2011..so obviously i've no idea of what it was...

Comment: ohh ok you ..actually you had commented that you made it work so i thought you will remeber something... yea its obvious that this is too old to remember ,, thanks anyways